# Generic Web Parser

Tags: java, parsing, html-parsing

I am trying to scrape data from two websites. I want to build a generic web parser to scrape those website. I need a generic parser because i might need to parse additional websites in the future. I want to parse the websites using java and store specific data in MySQL. What are the steps I should take?  Can anyone guide me in this?

Comment: This is much too broad, and you haven't indicated you've done any work on the problem yet. SO is intended to answer specific questions, not provide general tutorial/education on broad topics such as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this same thing for scraping the web using java and building a parser is an absolute nightmare, there are so many more things to consider that you realize at the start.

Use [jSoup](http://www.jsoup.org). It is sooo easy, and leaves you time to enjoy the finer things in life.

Comment: Yes, that's what I plan to use. I think using Jsoup and regular expressions should make it a bit easy. Thanks!

Comment: No worries! I really like too how jsoup has a "sandbox" so to speak where you can test stuff out - http://try.jsoup.org/, and the main page for learning how to use it is their "cookbook" (took me a while to find it, but it's a gem)

Comment: Hey if this works for you, would you mark it correct?